# Switch Error, Expected Primary Expression

Tags: switch-statement, solidity

Trying to use a switch-case statement in Solidity and getting an 'expected primary expression' error.

```
function foo(uint8 version) public {
    switch version
    case 1 {
        <do something>
    }
    default {
        revert();
    }
}
```

My exact error is

```
Error: Expected primary expression.
      --> project/contracts/MyContract.sol:149:9:
       |
   149 |         switch version
       |         ^^^^^^
```

Compiler version 8.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High-level solidity doesn't support `switch` in the current version 0.8. You can use a series of `if` / `else if` blocks instead.

```
function foo(uint8 version) public {
    if (version == 1) {
        // do something
    } else if (version == 2) {
        // do something else
    } else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

---

The Yul language in Solidity `assembly` blocks, that are usually used for low-level operations, does support `switch`.

```
function fooYul(uint8 version) public {
    assembly {
        switch version
        case 1 {
            // do something
        }
        case 2 {
            // do something else
        }
        default {
            revert(0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/yul.html#switch

Comment: Thanks! Was looking at docs for switch syntax used in assembly blocks not realizing Solidity didn't have switch syntax.